# Cannot receive Data from POST request in Next.js server API end point

Tags: reactjs, postman, next.js13

I am new to Next.js. I am writing an API endpoint, which is very simple. All it does is take data it receives, displays the data in a console log, and than responds with the recieved data. But for some reason, whenever I console log the the data recieved, it says it is undefined, and even when I respond with the returned data, I get nothing. What am I doing wrong here?

below is the console log in vs code
[image: console log]

below is the screenshot of postman response I get
[image: Postman screenshot]

```
import { request } from 'http';
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server'
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next'

export async function POST(
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse) {
    
const data = await req.body;

console.log("this is data I recieved => " + data.response);


return Response.json({message: "I am responde for route test2!!!!", test: data});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`NextRequest` extends [`Request`](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/v14.1.1-canary.80/packages/next/src/server/web/spec-extension/request.ts#L11) interface of the Fetch API.

The `json` instance method can be used to [parse the request body](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/json) (Refer to  [example](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/route-handlers#request-body)).

You can write:

```
  const data = await req.json();

  console.log("this is data I recieved => " + data.response);
```

Comment: when I do "const data = await req.json();" ir underlines the json() part and gives me this error when I have my cursor over it "Property 'json' does not exist on type 'NextApiRequest'."

Comment: these resources will be useful: 

Reddit - https://www.reddit.com/r/nextjs/comments/12i224x/request_vs_nextrequest_vs_nextapirequest_and/?rdt=40436

Next.Js Docs - https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/routing/api-routes#adding-typescript-types

as you are using App Router (I assume because you are defining a `POST` function and not a `handler` function), You should use NextRequest and NextResponse as types  in your `route.ts` file

Comment: Provide the hint for `req` as [`NextRequest`](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/c353b5f0e6a249fcbcf6d073909d203ec7f40768/packages/next/server.d.ts#L8) and not `NextApiRequest `. 
`import { type NextRequest } from 'next/server'`